# Cloud provider not initialized properly

Tags: kubernetes, vmware, vsphere, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I created storageclass and persistentvolumeclaim in the vSphere infrastructure. However, I am getting an error when I checked persistentvolumeclaim using kubectl describe pvc **pvc-name** command:

```
[root@kube-master-01 ~]# kubectl describe pvc jenkins-claim -n kube-jenkins
Name:          jenkins-claim
Namespace:     kube-jenkins
StorageClass:  fast
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{"volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class":"fast"},"name":"jen...
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                    From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                   ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  2m42s (x701 over 26h)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "fast": Cloud provider not initialized properly
```

The **storageclass.yml** and persistentvolumeclaim.yml used is as followings:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
parameters:
  datastore: VSANDatastore
  diskformat: thin
  fstype: xfs
```

The **persistentvolumeclaim.yml:**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-claim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5G
```

This problem occurs frequently in VMware vSphere environment.

Comment: Look at the logs of your kubelet

Comment: **The kubelet log is as shown:** `[root@kube-master-01 ssl]# journalctl -u kubelet | grep cloud
Mar 27 17:48:24 kube-master-01 kubelet[1974]: I0327 17:48:24.175454    1974 flags.go:33] FLAG: --cloud-config=""
Mar 27 17:48:24 kube-master-01 kubelet[1974]: I0327 17:48:24.175462    1974 flags.go:33] FLAG: --cloud-provider=""
Mar 27 17:48:24 kube-master-01 kubelet[1974]: I0327 17:48:24.301258    1974 plugins.go:100] No cloud provider specified.
Mar 27 17:48:24 kube-master-01 kubelet[1974]: I0327 17:48:24.301286    1974 server.go:526] No cloud provider specified: "" from the config file: ""
`

Comment: My kubernetes installation method is kubespray. In which file should I specify the cloud provider?

Comment: Please take a look here: [Kubespray - vSphere Cloud Provider](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/646fd5f47b931c073247e355f911bda5974745f3/docs/vsphere.md#vsphere-cloud-provider) Did you followed this step by step to create your PV?

Comment: Hi Yes, I did it step by step. I think that I also have a datastore problem in VMware vSphere. I could not configure it correctly. I continue looking for it on the internet.

Comment: I'd like to provide a few links that could help you solve your vSphere issue, for vSphere >= 6.7U3: The [External vSphere Cloud Provider](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-vsphere) along with [vSphere Container Storage Interface Driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/vsphere-csi-driver) are recommended, and you can learn more on [vSphere Kubernetes Documentation](https://cloud-provider-vsphere.sigs.k8s.io/). For vSphere < 6.7U3 see [Running a Kubernetes Cluster on vSphere with kubeadm](https://cloud-provider-vsphere.sigs.k8s.io/tutorials/k8s-vcp-on-vsphere-with-kubeadm.html)